# How to add a search parameter to an existing Ransack query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have a search form on a page, that allows a user to filter a list on multiple conditions. Now I'd like to add quick links on top of the list to apply scopes. I tried it like this:

```
= link_to "Visited", q: {"activated" => true}
```

While this filters the list to show only activated items, it also resets the search query. In other words, it doesn't remember what was already filtered in the form.

Is there a way to adapt `@q` so that I can add this `"activated" => true` to the hash of required filters?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're only using the :q param to filter, you could aggregate that.

```
= link_to "Visited", q: (params[:q] || {}).merge(activated: true)
```

Comment: Sounds interesting, I will test this tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can because if you follow a link you are not submitting the form therefore the parameters are not going to be submitted.

Passing the params in your link to will send the params if any exist:

```
= link_to "Visited", q: {"activated" => true, "your_params" => params}
```

This will only work if the form has been submitted once though, otherwise the params would be empty.

EDIT

I assume that the fields on your forms are populating if there is a value.

For example,

```
<%= text_field_tag(:email, if !params["email"].nil? then params["ip_email"] end) %>
```

Comment: That sounds plausible, but, the params contains a key q for the ransack params. So I don't see how this would work. Or I need to loop through each and every param. But that will be difficult in a link_to as well.